# MapReduce Program producing empty output

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce, mapper

I created a mapreduce program to take World Indicator Data to show the results of the specific indicator I wanted to analyze. (I.E. CO2 Emissions). The data is laid out in a long line that includes, the country, code, indictator, year 1 emission, year 2 emission, etc. In my mapper I tried to only keep the data that I wanted (First only keep the line if it has the specific indicator), then keep the country and all the emissions levels (in a string array).

My entire program runs, but I noticed that it is receiving Map input records, but there are no Map output records or Reduce Input/Output records.

I keep trying to figure out where my logic went wrong, but I'm stumped. Any input is appreciated.

My code is below:

---Mapper--

```
package org.myorg;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class CO2Mapper extends Mapper <LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>
{
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        String delims = ",";
        String splitString = value.toString();

        String[] tokens = splitString.split(delims);

        int tokenCount = tokens.length;
        String country = tokens[1]; 
        String indicator = tokens[3];
        int levels;

        if(indicator.equals("EN.ATM.CO2E.KT"))
        {   
            for (int j = 4; j < tokenCount; j++)
            {
                levels = Integer.parseInt(tokens[j]);
                context.write(new Text(country), new IntWritable(levels));
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

----reducer---

```
package org.myorg;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;


public class CO2Reducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>
{
    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(IntWritable val : values)
        {
            maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, val.get());
            minValue = Math.min(minValue, val.get());
        }

        context.write(key, new IntWritable(maxValue));
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(minValue));
    }
}
```

---main---

```
package org.myorg;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
//import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.KeyValueTextInputFormat;

public class CO2Levels 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  
    {    
        //with mapreduce

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = new Job(conf, "co2Levels");

        //Job job = new Job();

        job.setJarByClass(CO2Levels.class);
        //job.setJobName("co2Levels");
        job.setMapperClass(CO2Mapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(CO2Reducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        //job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to step through the code and observe it's behaviour for a single set of inputs?

Comment: can u provide a few sample input text ?

Comment: Ur program is fine. I think the problem is in the input. Perhaps 4th column of the file doesn't contain the required value, thus   failing the `if(indicator.equals("EN.ATM.CO2E.KT"))` condition.

Comment: @voidHead I tried adding debugger steps to see where it was stopping in my mapper, but I was having problems writing the code to be able to see it in my output (i.e. in the if stmt `System.out.println("1")`. The stmts weren't coming out in my terminal and I still had no output file. I'm stumped.

Comment: @blackSmith I saved the file as a .csv and converted it to .txt 
below is a sample line, unless you want me to upload a larger sample set.

Comment: @blackSmith (continued)
sample input: 

Algeria,DZA,CO2 emissions (kt),EN.ATM.CO2E.KT,6.16E+03,6.07E+03,5.67E+03,5.43E+03,5.65E+03,6.60E+03,8.43E+03,8.44E+03,9.06E+03,1.13E+04,1.51E+04,1.87E+04,2.83E+04,3.83E+04,3.19E+04,3.20E+04,3.92E+04,4.19E+04,6.25E+04,4.56E+04,6.65E+04,4.64E+04,3.93E+04,5.26E+04,7.11E+04,7.28E+04,7.63E+04,8.41E+04,8.39E+04,8.00E+04,7.89E+04,8.15E+04,8.23E+04,8.25E+04,8.64E+04,9.47E+04,9.66E+04,8.82E+04,1.07E+05,9.21E+04,8.79E+04,8.43E+04,9.09E+04,9.25E+04,8.95E+04,1.07E+05,1.04E+05,1.12E+05,1.15E+05,1.25E+05,1.23E+05,,,

Answer (score 1):

From the sample input i found that the token is in this format 6.16E+03
which is throwing an exception and cannot be parsed as an integer.

Also, if you want to check where your system.out.println() goes, [check this](http://www.hadoopforum.org/home.php?action=viewPost&topicId=84&topicdesc=where+does++System.out.println+goes&categoryId=32&catDesc=Map+Reduce+Programming)

Comment: this hadoop forum's link also indicate the place where stderr is placed along with stdout, helped me!!

Answer (score 0):

In your main you are not importing your map and reduce class. Add following to main:

```
import org.myorg.CO2Mapper;
import org.myorg.CO2Reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the sample input, seems that I've found the cause of the problem. The following codeblock in the `Mapper` is erroneous wrt the input :

```
 for (int j = 4; j < tokenCount; j++){
      levels = Integer.parseInt(tokens[j]);
```

From 5th column all numerical values are in floating point representation(eg: '8.44E+03') although they are indeed integers. Thus `Integer.parseInt` is throwing `NumberFormatException` and the job fails. I'm not convinced with *"My entire program runs"* statement (check the task logs at JobTracker). If you're certain that input will always contain integers, do something like :

```
  levels = (int) Float.parseFloat(tokens[j]);
```

Else change the data type of `levels` to float/double and use FloatWritable/DoubleWritable for map's output value class with related changes to reducer.

Another problem with the input is presence of empty fields, which will also produce `NumberFormatException` during parsing. Add some check like :

```
  if (tokens[j] != null || tokens.trim().isEmpty()){
         continue; // or do the needful. eg - set levels to 0 or some default value 
  }
```

Hope this will solve the issue. However I couldn't understand the logic you used in the reducer. This may be intentional but seems like your variables `maxValue` & `minValue` will always end with `Integer.MAX_VALUE` & `Integer.MIN_VALUE` due to the comparisons :

```
 maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, val.get());
 minValue = Math.min(minValue, val.get());
```

which means the above statements are usless or I'm missing the point.  Anyway good luck.